# How to get Page Manager to react on path alias before node/%node

Tags: 7, panels, path-aliases, chaos-tool-suite

I have a CTools Page Manager Panels Variant that I want to apply to a whole load of different content, based on paths. Basically I want this Page Manager Page to handle all paths matching:

```
foo/*/*
```

Some paths will be node path aliases, some will be generated in other ways, i.e. not nodes.

I've set up a Page Manager Page with one Variant on the path `foo/%blah/%baz`, and this works well.

The problem is that if `foo/bar/whatnot` is a node's path alias, Page Manager sees this as `node/1234` (it's menu path), and reacts with a different variant (`node/%node`), never considering the page page/variant I want.

My understanding of Drupal's "fitness" logic for menu router items would mean that my thing would win if the node's path alias was used, because `foo/%/%` has a fitness of 4, whereas `node/%` has a fitness of 2.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to override the default path like `node/%node`, `taxonomy/term/%taxonomy_term` and so on then there is a module for that: [Page manager existing pages](https://www.drupal.org/project/pm_existing_pages). Some more details about this module (from its project page):

> Page manager existing pages allows you to override/configure Drupal menu paths so you can create variants with Page manager, which is bundled in the CTools project.

Here is an introduction from the author: [Overriding any Drupal path with Page manager existing pages](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W-4g01WjwI4).